# Create Library Override of Data Block

Tags: python, linked-data, data-blocks

I want to access the "create library override" of a linked object in the data-block panel like shown in the image below via Python. When I do this, nothing appeared in the info panel. Is there any possible way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Got it:

```
obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
obj.data.override_create(remap_local_usages=True)
```

API link: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.override_create