# Library override collection using python

Tags: python

Hi maybe someone can help me figure out how to script this, how do a make a library override of a collection using python. I have figured out how to do it on a single object `bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type='OVERRIDE_LIBRARY_CREATE_HIERARCHY')`

But I would like to simply give a collection object or name as input and then make the library override the contents of the collection. Just as this action.

[image]

Comment: maybe this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177657/16634

Answer (score 0):

Using this code is te solution to the problem:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.make_override_library()
```