# Cannot create library override

Tags: python, scripting, linked-data, data-blocks, library-overrides

I'm trying to create a library override after linking objects into my scene like this:

```
import bpy

filepath = '/path/goes/here/Testing.blend'

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath,link=True) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = data_from.objects

scene=bpy.context.scene
collection_name="Linked"

try:
    link_to = scene.collection.children[collection_name]
except KeyError:
    link_to = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    scene.collection.children.link(link_to)

for obj in data_to.objects:
    if obj is not None:
        try:
            link_to.objects.link(obj)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active =obj
            obj.data.override_create(remap_local_usages=True)
        except:
            print("already exists!")
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect

I tried [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269681/131649) solution:

```
link_to.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active =obj
bpy.ops.object.make_override_library()
```

but this seems to make duplicates for some reason
[image]

I also tried [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269681/131649) solution but it also does nothing,
so how do I library override objects?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I figured it out

```
for obj in data_to.objects:
    if obj is not None:
        try:
            link_to.objects.link(obj.override_create(remap_local_usages=True))
        except:
            print("already exists!")
```